# Handle several adjacent regex matches

Tags: python, regex

Having a regex pattern which can be found several times in a text, how would one chooses and differs between the matches in this case?

- choose the first match.
- ignore the peripherals.
- only one match using index.

---

**Example:**

```py
regex_pattern = r"(AB.+?AbB)|(CD.+?CdD)|(EF.+?EfF)"

text = "for finding several CDadjacent CDtagsCdDCdD in a 
        text this is an ABexampleAbB text"
```

the first match is **CDadjacent CDtagsCdD**.
while one might wants to match both:
**CD**adjacent **CD**tags**CdDCdD**
and. . . . . . . **CD**tags**CdD**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer faster than I thought.
using '(',')' (round brackets) lets you use parts of the regex as one unit and by adding the '+; (plus sign) you can look for more than one occurrences of a pattern.

for this example this pattern will solve the issue:

```
r"(AB.+?(AbB)+)|(CD.+?(CdD)+)|(EF.+?(EfF)+)"
```